# Softening meat with the vinegar / lemon / onion / pineapple etc. How does it work?

Tags: meat, vinegar, acidity

And why does acid make the meat softer?

Comment: The question in the title looks like an abbreviated version of this question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20654/why-marinade-meat-with-acid-or-enzymes?rq=1 See also https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/89245/25059 which discusses other tenderizing techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate question but think about the enzymes; the acids break down protein in meats to smaller sizes and therefore easier to fall apart. A good comparison is what your stomach does to food, the longer the brine etc. penetrates the meat the more tender it will be (within reason of course).

Comment: If it's a duplicate, there's no need to post an answer here - the answers on the previous question would cover it. If there's something that you think is missing there, please add it there.